# Spacing between characters inside of HTML <td> tag - why does it become stretched out?

Tags: html, css, html-table, netsuite, letter-spacing

I am working with an HTML table that is misbehaving when it comes to semi-long lengths of text. The picture below is worth 1000 words. In the first cell shown, the text "Embroidered Lettering Only" becomes stretched out as far as 'between character spacing' goes. It looks like its happening on the next cell as well in the "FLOSS" text.

Is there an attribute that I can use to prevent this behavior? Most of my search results have mostly produced *table* spacing issues, not text inside of a cell. The only attribute on the table that relates to size is `<table width="100%">` I would prefer to conquer this with an inline attribute, but I can work with almost anything.

Note that I have tried `letter-spacing= "0"` and other values, to no avail. It is modifying the spacing behavior, but a value of 0 does not change this to normal spacing in the screenshot example.

I don't think it matters, but this is HTML that is being converted to a PDF through the BFO engine, within a NetSuite environment

[image: table with inconsistent character spacing]

Comment: you probably have `text-align: justify`.

Comment: Is the letter spacing issue in the HTML on the page, or only when you convert it to a PDF?

Comment: Here is something I would do. Take your code into jsfiddle or codepen. See if it is doing it there (which I doubt it is), then you can actually discern if it is a CSS issue (which my assumption is it is not). Then my assumption is the PDF generator code is what is messing up your text.

Comment: Normally I would, but this all takes place within a NetSuite environment, and there's no generated HTML before being converted to PDF. I believe that you're right, however, that the PDF generator is messing up the text. I removed all of the CSS and put in a normal HTML table, and the same issue arises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've come across this issue using Netsuite  / BFO, the solution is to use this CSS:

```
td p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Source (login required): https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/bfo/397738-how-do-i-prevent-text-justification-advanced-pdf-freemarker-bfo

Comment: Marked this as correct as it is more relevant to the environment in which is happened. Thank you for adding your answer. I asked this several years ago and had forgotten, and it just helped me solve the issue again.

Answer (score 3):

Marc B mentioned it in his comment, you probably have `text-align: justify;` somewhere in your CSS for the table. Try tracking that down and changing it to `text-align: left;`

For example:

```
table td {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Would want to be changed to:

```
table td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

That being said, it's hard to know for sure without seeing your current markup and CSS, so it would probably be a good idea to add that to your post.

Comment: Normally I would share the markup, but this all takes place within a NetSuite environment, and there's no generated HTML before being converted to PDF. I believe that you're right, however, that the PDF generator is messing up the text. I removed all of the CSS and put in a normal HTML table, and the same issue arises.

Comment: Im marking this as correct though, as I believe it would be the answer if this was not inside the Netsuite environment. Thanks.